# Magento 1.9 CE State Region confusion

Tags: payment, address, state

My payment gateway (Ecorepay) requires customer address to include `state/province`.

It works when I pass the `region_id` (for countries where I have a drop down list) my question is where is the region stored if there is no drop down list and the value has simply been added as free text? Can see it in any of the order table in the database...

Answer (score 0):

The region name is kept in the `region` attribute of the address.
So if you call `$address->getRegion()` you will get the region name in both cases (where region_id is populated and when it's not).

Comment: Thanks Marius
at the moment the code is...

'$regionModel = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->load($billingaddress->getData('region_id'));'

then

''State'=> $regionModel->getCode(),'

How do i get simply the region from $address

Comment: `$billingaddress->getRegion()`

Comment: Great that's a great help.  I'm now having problems because when the 'country' is US it's expecting a 2 character code eg TX rather than Texas but requires the free text from other countries!